# Foreach loop (or do while maybe?) - Want to return only one record depending on page

Tags: php, loops, variables, foreach, do-while

### Solved this with edited code below. Thanks to all who helped!

I have two records in my db.  Each record has 6 fields (challengeId, partnerName, code, challengeTitle, description, image_url).  I select a given partnerName from my parent page view to go to my child page view.

I was using a foreach loop and having problems. I have now taken out my foreach loop and replaced it with `<?php $challengename = $this->challengenames[$k] = current($this->challengenames); ?>` but now cannot get the child page to display the values for challengeTitle that correspond to 'partnerName' I chose on my parent page.  It always provides the challengeTitle value of the first record instead of the current record.  I need to know how to make the challengeTitle value change depending on which partnerName I chose on my parent page.

Will making this a do while loop or if statement in the child page controller fix this?

Any advice (and code changes) is very much appreciated.

---

### parent page controller

```
public function viewChallengesAction(){
    //get instance for request
    $request = JO_Request::getInstance();
    //get activated challenge names and set variables
    $myChallenge=$this->getChallenge();
    $this->view->challengenames = array();
    foreach($myChallenge AS $k=>$challengename){
        $this->view->challengenames[$k]['href'] = WM_Router::create($request->getBaseUrl() . '?module=challenges&controller=index&action=yourChallenge?code=' . $challengename['partnerName']);
        $this->view->challengenames[$k]['partnerName'] = $challengename['partnerName'];
    }
```

---

### CHILD VIEW

```
<div id="defaultcontainerwrapper" class="maxwidth">
    <?php $challengename = $this->challenge; ?>
        <header>
        <h1>
            <div class="list">
                <span>Welcome to </span><?php echo $challengename['partnerName']; ?><span>'s Beat Waste Challenge!</span>
             </div>
        </h1>
        </header>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

---

### CHILD CONTROLLER

```
public function yourChallengeAction(){
    //get activated challenge names and set variables
    $request = JO_Request::getInstance();
    $myChallenge=$this->getChallenge();
    $code = $request->getQuery("code");
    $this->view->challengenames = array();
    foreach($myChallenge AS $k=>$challengename){
        if ($challengename['partnerName'] == $code)
        {
            $this->view->challenge = $challengename;
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you get rid of `{ }` and add a `;` at the end of the statement, and are you certain there will always be a first element in the array?

Comment: What is `$k`? when you say current, do you mean the index that the foreach loop is currently on?

Comment: Yes, I mean the index that the loop is currently on.  I did add the ; and it got me out of the loop but it didn't display the value for challengenames[$k]  . Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: post the array value in `$myChallenge` using `var_dump($myChallenge)` and what is the condition you need to use in `foreach` and what you need to store in `challengenames`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the key and want the current element of the array, you could use:

```
$challengename = current($this->challengenames);
```

Or the first element of the array:

```
$challengename = reset($this->challengenames);
```

Or the last element of the array:

```
$challengename = end($this->challengenames);
```

Just note that end and reset will change the pointer location of the array.

Comment: Tx Devon. This got me part of the way there but perhaps I am now missing something else.  I changed the first line to:      `<?php $challengename = $this->challengenames[$k] = current($this->challengenames); ?>`  Now, I am only getting one record but it is always the first record.  I want to be on the current record.  I have pasted my view and controller code above.  I don't think I am explaining very well, but I come to this page from a previous page using the unique identifier varibale challengeId, which you can see in the controller code. Tx again!

Comment: How are you defining/determining the "current" record?

Comment: Tx Devon.  I have edited the above text and have added the parent controller and view. Do I need to make this a do while loop now?  Again, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This helped me a lot Devon. I have now solved this problem and changed the code above to the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php $challengename = $this->challengenames[0] ?>
```

You are missing a last ; try add it agaign;
try below:

```
  <?php $challengename = $this->challengenames[0]; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much, Bo. That seems to get me out of the loop but in getting rid of the [$k], I now no longer have a value.  Any idea on how to weave the $k back into the new equation so I get my value?

Comment: Following from [your reposted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887034/foreach-loop-return-only-one-record), `0` is the value of `$k` you're looking for

Comment: I tried that, Havelock, but replacing 0 with $k returns no values. Very new to all this.