# foreach loop - return only one record

Tags: php, loops, variables, foreach, record

My db has two records with multiple fields (e.g. partnerName, image_url, etc).  The foreach loop pasted below works perfectly, returning the two values 'partnerName' from the two records.
I now  only want to return the value from the current record.

I replaced the following line:
    `<?php foreach($this->challengenames as $k=>$challengename) { ?>`

with
    `<?php $challengename = $this->challengenames[0]; ?>`
and got rid of the ending php bracket.
This gets rid of the loop, but I lose the index k so I get no values.  Any advice on how to modify this loop to retain the index k but return only the value for the current record?

Many thanks!

```
<div id="defaultcontainerwrapper" class="maxwidth">
<?php foreach($this->challengenames as $k=>$challengename) { ?>
    <header>
        <h1>
            <div class="list">
                <span>Welcome to </span><?php echo $challengename['partnerName']; ?><span>'s Beat Waste Challenge!</span>
            </div>
        </h1>
    </header>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `0` is the new `$k` ;)

Comment: why did you repost? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886181/foreach-loop-want-to-return-only-one-record-depending-on-page please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: Sorry Sean. New here and just learning about the site.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code -

```
<div id="defaultcontainerwrapper" class="maxwidth">
    <header>
        <h1>
            <div class="list">
                <span>Welcome to </span><?php echo $this->challengenames[0]['partnerName']; ?><span>'s Beat Waste Challenge!</span>
            </div>
        </h1>
    </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$k is the key of $challengname starting with 0

```
foreach($this->challengenames as $key => $value) {
    $key[0] = $value['partnername'];
    $key[1]=$value['image_url'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by current record? Because I assume `$this->challengenames` refers to the output from maybe  `fetchAll()` in PDO, returning an array of database rows (as associative arrays). So by using `$this->challengenames[0]` you are getting the first row returned (based on the order set in the SQL query).

Index $k in your solution refers to 0. Anyway you're aren't even using $k within your loop o.o

If you wanna return only one row use fetch() or mysql_get_row() (not recommended) or equivalent. And your SQL query should have `LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the latest data from you DB then i recommend you to fetch the data in descending order and retrieving only a single row as mention below

`select * from <your table> orderby DESC`

now you don't have to run a loop just use the 0th index to get the latest data

Comment: Tx Karvin.  It is a small dataset and I have all the variables already, just trying to get the loop sorted out.  I think I have it using `<?php $challengename = $this->challengenames[$k] = current($this->challengenames); ?>`   Now it is only returning the first value but I want it to return the value from the record I used to get to this page. Not sure if that makes sense but I used a value 'challengeId' to get to this page and now I want to use that value 'challengeId' to fetch other values on that page.  I'm sure I'm  going about this the wrong way but I am very new to this. Tx again!